# Choose 2nd GPU on server

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

I am running code on server. There are 2 GPUs there, and the 1st one is busy. Yet, I can't find a way to switch between them. I am using pytorch if that is important. Following lines of code should be modified:

```
device = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'
```

Modification may be stated only here.
Thanks.

Comment: I understand that you want to only modify those lines (and Andrew Naguib's answer does that). But, you might want to use a more generic solution where you can run on any GPU without changing code i.e. use `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1` (replace 1 with GPU ID) as a prefix to your command (or run `export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1` before running your command).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`cuda` by defaults chooses `cuda:0`, switching to the other GPU may be done through `cuda:1`

So, your line becomes:

```
device = 'cuda:1' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'
```

You can read more about [CUDA semantics](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/cuda.html#cuda-semantics).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way I'm doing it while using FastAI and pre-trained model for inference.
First, while model definition with fai (`import fastai.vision.all as fai`) I obtain the model instance and put it to specified GPU (say with `gpu_id=3`):

```
model = fai.nn.Sequential(body, head)
model.cuda(device=gpu_id)
```

Then, while loading model weights I also specify which device to use (otherwise it creates the copy of a model in GPU 0):

```
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(your_model_state_filepath, torch.device(gpu_id)))
```